# Laravel is csrf_field() needed in form when using axios

Tags: laravel, csrf, axios

I wonder if I need to include `{{ csrf_field() }}` inside my `<form>` when I do a ajax post request on that form using Axios.

In my bootstrap I already setup some kind of csrf protection like this:

```
//Add headers to axios
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
  window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
  console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

// html

```
<!-- CSRF Token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, when you're adding the CRSF-token to the axios headers, there's no need to include crsf_field in the form. It's appended on all headers, as it's already added to axios default headers.